# Input Stream not working in command prompt

Tags: java, cmd, bufferedreader, filereader

Hi Ive made a Java program which read lines from a CSV as data records. The problem im getting is the program works perfectly in eclipse console, however when I try to run the problem from cmd using Java compiler I doesnt work where my code specifies the location of the CSV file its show a error there as unknown. Ive tried everything such as moving the file into another package or using some other code to read the file Im getting the same result which is in eclipse it works but in the actual cmd it not working. Bellow is the ERROR and the method which reads the file.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\PostCodeENW.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)


public void loadfile() {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")); 
        String csvFile = "src/PostcodeENW.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";

        try { 
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] ar = line.split("/");

                PostCode = ar[0].trim().replaceAll("  ", " ");
                String[] ar1 = PostCode.split("\\s");
                String PostCodeP1 = ar1[0];
                String PostCodeP2 = ar1[1];
                int Easting = Integer.parseInt(ar[1]);
                int Northing = Integer.parseInt(ar[2]);
                String Ward = ar[3];

                Location geo = new Location(PostCodeP1, PostCodeP2, Easting, Northing, Ward);
                map.put(geo.getkey(), geo.getValue());
//          System.out.println(PostCodeP1 + " " + PostCodeP2 + " " + Easting + " " + Northing + " " + Ward); 
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done Adding all records");
        System.out.println("Database currently holds: " + map.size()); //Test how much elements are currently in the HashMap
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running the java file from? It's looking for a folder "src" in the current directory, then a file "PostcodeENW.csv" in the folder "src".
So if the command line is in a different directory to where that folder and file are located it would give you an error.

Try to run the java file in the same directory as where the folder "src" is located

In command line change directory to the eclipse workspace using `cd %HOMEPATH%/Documents/workspace`
If the eclipse workspace is in your user's folder, in your documents, in a folder called workspace.

Comment: Finally it works but I dont understand when you make a new project in Eclipse you get a folder called src and then the default package I imported the CSV file and it automatically when into the default package. If I actually look in my project folder I have 2 folder and 2 files called bin, src, .classpath and .project Does this mean I should copy the content of bin into the directory and delete the bin folder ? Or do I need to change my code abit ?

Comment: If you're happy to have the Java file run from eclipse, then no need to delete bin. But if you want to run the Java file from the command line, you'll need to copy the contents of bin into src so the Java file can see the csv file.
Personally I'd recommend copying the csv file into bin and src folders.

Answer (score 0):

Once compiled, the `src` path will no longer exist. As I understand eclipse, it will only jar class files from the `src` folder, this means, once compiled and packaged, it's unlikely that the file `PostcodeENW.csv` will even exist.

Two things you need to try,

First, move the `PostcodeENW.csv` file into the resources directory within your project

Once build and a packaged, eclipse will include the contents of the resources directory within the jar.  This means that these resources will no longer be accessible as files,but will become embedded resources

Secondly, change your code so that when you read the file, you read it as an embedded resource, for example

```
String csvFile = "/PostcodeENW.csv";
//...
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsInputStream(csvFile)));
```

Nb- I don't use eclipse, so I'm going what I understand needs to be done, but these are the basic ideas ;)

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer now I known about properly organising resources and using them lol